# Why did my label not display below a select widget

Tags: css, html

I think this maybe a stupid question but I really could not figure out what is wrong with what I am doing

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table border="1" height = "300px">
 <tr>
   <td>Cell A</td>
   <td>Cell B</td>
   <td>
      <div id="myCellContainer">
         <select id="mySelect"/>
         <label id="myMessage">My label</label>
      </div>
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

When this is rendered I was expecting my label to show up below the select box but it did not. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
<select id="mySelect"></select>
```

This method won't be a self-closing tag.

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem. I thought I could do <x/> wherever <x></x> was expected but clearly I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `<label>` is inside the `<select>` element. Look at the rendered mark-up. The  element is not a valid self-closing, or void, element, as described by [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-elements).

It should be:

`<select></select>`

Once you fix this however, you'll still need to apply block level display to put the label on it's own line:

```
#myMessage {
  display:block;
}
```

But the deeper question here is, why are you using a `<table>` to layout a `<form>`? Form elements are not tabular data. The information you enter *into* the `<form>` may be tabular, but the `<form>` itself it is not. Perfectly adequate positioning and styling can be achieved purely with CSS and the appropriate containers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your `html` correctly. Also you need to give the label a `width` of `100%`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/LstNS/36/

Answer (score 0):

You could css the select to `{ display: block }` or you could put a `<br/>` after the select. As it sits your select is an inline-block and following markup occupies the same line unless it wraps.